# How to break long words in a table td?

Tags: css, html-table, word-wrap

This is what I have:

```
<td style='width:        500px;
           white-space:  pre-wrap;
           white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
           white-space: -pre-wrap; 
           white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
           word-wrap:    break-word;'>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this solution will help you!

```
pre {
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
}
```

http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/06/01/wrapping-content/

---

// Edit

It's been a long time since this was accepted as the best answer and updates are required. See @benhowdle89's and @Steve's answers below.

So the current browser support is now good enough to use `word-break` in order to allow words to be broken over multiple lines.

`word-break: break-all`

http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Also, you can post up to 30,000 characters here, so there's really no reason to use a URL shortener.

Comment: it doesn't work well is there a chance you know another way to acomplish this

Answer (score 36):

I used:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
table-layout: fixed;
```

`table-layout: fixed` was the key to making it work.

Comment: `word-break: break-all` did it for me.

Comment: thanks for the distinction between `word-wrap` and `word-break`!

Comment: `word-wrap` and `word-break` are not CSS 2.1 properties

Comment: For me `white-space: break-spaces;` works

Answer (score 14):

```
word-break: break-word;
```

This is what you want

Comment: This works in some browsers, however not in IE for me. `word-break:break-all` works in both and appears to be the standard.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is

`word-break:break-all`

This works in [Chrome 4+, IE 5.5+, FF 15+, Safari 3.1+, and Opera 15+](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)