# How to deal with long links in HTML-emails

Tags: php, html-email

I've searched the web on this and I can find two solutions:

1. Use a URL-shortner.
2. Use brackets `<` `>` to allow insertion of whitespace. This only applies to plain-text emails.

I'm sending HTML emails that contains sensitive information, like password recovery links and auto-authentication links. These secure links are, by their nature, quite long. Easily longer than 70 characters or whatever arbitrary limit is imposed on e-mail bodies.

Obviously I can't use any form of URL-shortning because it would circumvent any secure cryptography technique I've used for the links.

I suppose the largest issue is that the links aren't wrapped nicely by email clients. The nice word-wrapping is supported in CSS3 technique, so there is no way MS Outlook will ever support this.

**How do I make it so the links are not visually disruptive and possibly easy to copy-paste in case of email client malfunction?**

*Example*

> If the link doesn't seem to work, try copy-pasting it to your browser:
>   hxxp://development/#auth/YoxOntz0Oj0ExOiJfcmFuG9tbmVzcyI7czoxOTI6kJsYkV0qMGMuZ1pFZVQ5YkRQNDZPR200Unl60dGlpNlhZZC9QcEVeH0lvV2NVVlpWWFcwWlF0VjRyc0p4akYzclJ0GTkJmSlgxco0aEtDS0FuTlBVSXAxUVhCcGdRNGpHMVl5UGZMRFVacDVSQ1BqcU0tKYlNxZ0FqYXpjTkNqTS9LV29xSk4ydGtyeFpNdV0c2VLMERUbEYwc08xUWU5aXR0GOXl0bVFpcjlXeGZjUE100S0o1L1FcmQ4MmhOdm5LUSI7fQ

Additional notes:

I do not want my links to expire. If I want them to expire at all I'd have a time frame of months, not hours. These links are not just password recovery links.

Comment: Why are URLs so long in the first place? When I've coded password retrieval systems, I've just created a hash that expires in say, 24 hours. No need for it to be 70+ characters then.

Comment: Use a algorithmic that generates shorter urls? MD5 still perfect for this.

Comment: As long as you're using a cryptographic algorithm to generate the random value, it doesn't matter how you hash it. For instance, if you're generating the string using [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://www.php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes), you can even just urlencode or base64encode it. It's only important to ensure you can't predict the string and that it has enough entropy to avoid brute force attacks.

Comment: I can not use `md5` because there is readable information in the URL (I've obfuscated the example). I'm using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes to feed some of the cryptography techniques, but as the URL contains actual data 'just' randomness isn't enough. This would be the same as using URL-shortning.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried the Microsoft proprietary word-break:break-all; ?

```
<td style=“word-break:break-all;”>
```

---

This worked best for me (best compatibility across vendors):

```
<p style="word-break:break-all;">
    <font style="word-break:break-all;">hxxp://really_long_link</font>
</p>
```

Tested on: MS Office 2007/2010, outlook.com, hotmail.com, gmail.com, yahoo.com (yahoo did not display nicely)

---

While this was edited to include `<p>...</p>` I would highly discourage the use of paragraph tags in HTML email if spacing is impotant since email clients interpret these differently.

Comment: I've confirmed that this works in MS Outlook at least. I'll have to do some more testing, but it looks promising.

Comment: I checked some of the larger online mail suppliers and this code seems to work. I've updated the answer with the code that worked best for me (best compatibility across vendors).

Comment: NOTE: This breaks word-wrapping for normal text! Your words will be cutoff in the middle on all clients if contained in a tag with this style.

Comment: Note `<p>` tags are fine to use, re "I would highly discourage the use of paragraph tags", because all you need to do is set the desired margins. I.e. a mini CSS-reset like so: `<p style="margin:0">` or `margin: 20px 0` for a nice gap top and bottom.

Answer (score 3):

### In Html emails - use html

If you are sending html emails, what's wrong with:

```
... <a href="long url">reset your password</a> ...
```

If the links are getting mangled when you send html emails - the problem is how you're sending emails, not the recipient's email client.

### Use a shorter hash

Is a super long hash (is it a hash, or is it encrypted?) really necessary? Using any hash that is long enough to not be brute-forced before it expires aught to be sufficient. Asking users to copy and paste a string that is obviously going to wrap isn't going to help the user, it's just pushing a development problem onto the user.

Comment: `<textarea>` doesn't work in Outlook (and I would assume most other email programs). The tag is completely ignored.

Comment: Generating shorter hashes is certainly something I'm considering, but even a simple `base64_encoded` `sha512` hash is pretty damn long.

Comment: I think I have explained it, perhaps not obviously enough: some of the links are auto-authentication links (skipping an explicit user login). The link you posted about sha1 safety is not applicable since an attacker could easily learn more information about how the hashes are generated. This is an actual functioning application, not just a blind attack on a hash. I would downvote the comment if I could because it is dangerous to think about security in this way.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are emailing users encrypted authentication urls - instead of showing them the link on a secure webpage where they can act with it appropriately (drag to bookmarks). It doesn't matter how long you make the hash if it appears in plaintext in an email. Using encryption instead of a hash is the main reason your urls are so long - and the main problem. just use a hash/token table and that part of the problem goes away - and permits you to invalidate a token at any time as well as disassociate the emailed url from the user's credentials

Comment: Don't do this (```<a href="long url">reset your password</a>```). This approach will increase your spam score, as anti-spam solutions will think your links are trying to conceal the destination. Conclusion: To avoid being flagged as spam, an anchor's href and text should always be the same string.

Comment: @TomDogg Are you saying links should be `<a href="exactly the same">exactly the same</a>` to avoid being flagged as spam ...? Do you have a reference to support that? spamassasin for example has no rule for that, and [you don't have to try hard to find html being used as html in emails](http://ad7six.com/dump/analytics.png) - I call FUD on that :).

Comment: @AD7six Spammers do it: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/obfuscated_URL.html And spammer behavior gets mirrored in anti-spam filters.