# Is link wrapping an issue in HTML mails?

Tags: html, css, email, email-client

It is well known that link wrapping is a problem in text mails. Some mail readers wrap the link and only convert the first part into a clickable link. This causes broken links.

Is this an issue in HTML mails? It seems no because links are explicitly marked up using `<a>` elements.

Comment: Have you tried `word-break:break-all;` like [provided in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389079/6022243).

Comment: In a text mail there is no such thing. In HTML mails I wonder if this is a problem at all.