# HTML emails in Outlook: Long URLs result in broken links

Tags: html, url, outlook, href

We send transactional emails through Sendgrid, and some versions of Outlook mess up the links. They cut them off, so a link like this:

```
http://links.qarmainspect.com/wf/click?upn=6eONAhGc7sN4EJlyqwg4FRMGC7eHKcIyuF9puTG8Gdnt0414ekjCSP9y1nHpNyVnSL2XbkZetKzO5dcxRR5N7AUzI-2FfIPQjjFNr3U0oZYeLzfG1Phwn34caFriQl3wLZ-2FYTI8y9UqQ8Ra2txQp-2FRXg-3D-3D_5LntF25ee-2FgjH1O-2F4Mz8hGuijHJreXa9ITpWWjYLOL71U7heZBx0IDEy1R-2FJqvahB7gJI-2FynNAxWYeroBDTIVQ0LR6oXl9XZynESjbiMgVDDq896MrF-2F1pQqboUIu6oTqlzAFsLFscwovT5PbIbzGXB6a036Gnue2A4f5fatX2mm463AwgmCWnHRYq6l4fL2oOLdpplM4dwWSWgD5BOvOw-3D-3D
```

Ends up in the browser like this:

```
http://links.qarmainspect.com/wf/click?upn=6eONAhGc7sN4EJlyqwg4FRMGC7eHKcIyuF9puTG8Gdnt0414ekjCSP9y1nHpNyVnSL2XbkZetKzO5dcxRR5N7AUzI-2FfIPQjjFNr3U0oZYeLzfG1Phwn34caFriQl3wLZ-2FYTI8
```

Any idea how to avoid this?

Here is the HTML for the link:

```html
<a href="http://links.qarmainspect.com/wf/click?upn=6eONAhGc7sN4EJlyqwg4FRMGC7eHKcIyuF9puTG8Gdnt0414ekjCSP9y1nHpNyVnSL2XbkZetKzO5dcxRR5N7AUzI-2FfIPQjjFNr3U0oZYeLzfG1Phwn34caFriQl3wLZ-2FYTI8y9UqQ8Ra2txQp-2FRXg-3D-3D_5LntF25ee-2FgjH1O-2F4Mz8hGuijHJreXa9ITpWWjYLOL71U7heZBx0IDEy1R-2FJqvahB7gJI-2FynNAxWYeroBDTIVQ0LR6oXl9XZynESjbiMgVDDq896MrF-2F1pQqboUIu6oTqlzAFsLFscwovT5PbIbzGXB6a036Gnue2A4f5fatX2mm463AwgmCWnHRYq6l4fL2oOLdpplM4dwWSWgD5BOvOw-3D-3D" style="text-decoration: underline; border: solid 1px; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">See Report and Reply →</a>
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like bit.ly? I would assume the link is too long.

Comment: Maybe these links will help for you:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/why-does-outlook-2013-sometime-cuts-off-long-site/03d8d560-460f-46af-b5b0-7ec0b6ee35c6

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385891/how-to-deal-with-long-links-in-html-emails

Comment: I'm not able to use bit.ly addresses as they are generated by Sendgrid.

Comment: Thank you @AlinaLi, but this refers to problems sending links in emails from Outlook, not receiving them.

Comment: Søren, what about it? Could you solve this issue?

Comment: There's nothing that can be done about this, it's the way Outlook is programmed unfortunately.