# Word Break on mail Clients

Tags: css, html-email

Does styles attributes such as

```
word-break: break-all;
```

work on all major mail clients such as gmail, yahoo, outlook, apple and linux clients?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096012/break-long-words-in-html-email-in-outlook-2010