# Wrapping table data without table-layout?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I need to wrap text within a `<td>` element, but I can't use the css `table-layout` property as the output is to html e-mail body and Outlook doesn't support the `table-layout` property.

Is there some other way to wrap text within a `<td>` element, or do I need to do the line breaking and measuring manually in code?

Here is an example of what I am trying to acheive:

```css
td {
  border: solid black 1pt;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10pt
}

thead td{
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table style="width:35pt;height:24pt;table-layout:fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:35pt;height:12pt">Good</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:35pt;height:12pt;word-wrap:break-word">Costingly Cost Cost</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <div style="height:50pt"></div>

  <table style="width:35pt;height:24pt;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:35pt;height:12pt">Bad</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:35pt;height:12pt" nowrap>Costingly Cost Cost</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give this method a try: [HTML TD wrap text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057574/html-td-wrap-text). I know its not for emails but for tables in general.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no good. All the proposed solutions relied on using either the `table-layout` or `max-width` css properties; neither of which are supported by Outlook.

Comment: this is for emails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096012/break-long-words-in-html-email-in-outlook-2010

Comment: That suggestion appears to work out for me, if you want to write it up as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Answer added below for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Microsoft proprietary word-break:break-all;

```
<td style="word-break:break-all;">
```

That should fix things.

Comment: As a note for anyone reading this, I ended up with `<td style="word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word">` which resulted in the correct wrapping behaviour in both Outlook and Gmail (I haven't yet tested with other clients).

Comment: Thanks K you for the one up :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<tr>
<td nowrap>Never increase, beyond what is necessary, the number of entities required to explain anything</td>
<td>Never increase, beyond what is necessary, the number of entities required to explain anything</td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work, while the text does wrap, it wraps at the word breaks which can increase the width of the `<td>` element. If I use `table-layout:fixed` and `word-wrap:break-word` then I get the correct wrapping while maintaining the width of the `<td>`. I'll add an example snippet in the question to elaborate.