# How to keep text inside the parent?

Tags: html, css

Lets say take this as an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="s.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container {
    margin:10px;
    width:400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And it displays like so:

[image]

What do I do to place this kind of texts always within the parent div?

Comment: You have a text string which would not normally exist in the real world where the total width the character/letter images exceeds the set width of parent element. In the unlikely event of this happening you would use `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `word-wrap:break-word`.

```
#container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3N45g/)

Alternatively, you could also use `overflow:hidden`, which will hide the overflow. This is assuming you don't want the text to wrap. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UW2Pt/)

Lastly, there is `overflow:scroll` which will allow you to scroll through the overflow. Note - there will always be a scrollbar regardless of the length of the text. To avoid this you could also use `overflow:auto`. I don't know what you want. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc8Qk/) of `overflow:scroll`

Comment: Thanks! word-wrap was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: Probably, your desired behavior is JoshC's answer, but my answer keeps text inside the parent too (in another way).

Use [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) different than `visible` (i.e `auto`, `scroll` or `hidden`).

On most cases, I recommend `auto`:

```
#container {
    margin:10px;
    width:400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3N45g/1/)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Normally, the desired behavior is JoshC's answer, but my answer keeps text inside the parent too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a text string which would not normally exist in the real world where the total width the character/letter images exceeds the set width of parent element.

In the unlikely event of this happening you would use `word-wrap: break-word;`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6SZYD/) with ***normal*** text.

Comment: Actually I was thinking, what do i do if the users just post this kind of string in the post! Anyways thanks though! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely that you will have a single word or string such long length without any spaces. Please reconsider the length of your actual content. Using `overflow:hidden` you will only hide the extra text outside of the container, i assume thats what you wouldn't want. If you really need a single word which is this much (or even more) long then you need to use `word-wrap:break-word` or `word-break:break-word`. Still you can read the following posts for further reference.

[how to use automatic css hyphens with word-break: break-all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261605/how-to-use-automatic-css-hyphens-with-word-break-break-all)

[How to break long words in a table td?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284990/css-how-to-break-long-words-in-a-table-td)

http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/