# prevent text to line break if overflow

Tags: css

I do not want to specify the width of an area and set `overflow:hidden` or scroll to my text because the site is responsive. is there any way to prevent a line of text go to second line?

or example `"lorem sum etc ger ergdfg  efdfg"`

will not become

```
"lorem sum etc ger 
ergdfg  efdfg"
```

when width is small?

Comment: have you tried `word-wrap` and `white-space: nowrap` css property..?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the element containing the text.

The name is pretty self-explanatory - it makes the whitespace not wrap.

Use `overflow: hidden;` if you don't want the text to go out of the box it's supposed to be in.

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` if you want ellipsis when the text overflows the bounding box.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL2Dd/4/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 1+ **[This is all I have to say.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744299/how-to-keep-text-inside-the-parent/19744320#comment29338035_19744320)**

Comment: @JoshC Haha, revenge! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `white-space : nowrap`.

Example is available below

```
<span>lorem sum etc ger ergdfg efdfg</span>

<style>
span
{
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:scroll;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space : nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really offer anything more than the answer offered by Doorknob. Can you expand on the answer and include explanations for why this code should be used?