# How to make a paragraph not show in one line

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a paragraph with alot of text inside but this text is showing all in one line. How can I format this text so it will not mess up my site and not show it in a single line?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit:

This is my code:

```
<div class="catDescription">
    <?php echo $this->category->description; ?>
</div>
```

You can check here what my issue is:

http://complusoft.net/demo-ventus/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=29&Itemid=334

Comment: Can we have some code here?

Comment: Added the code to the question, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep text inside the parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744299/how-to-keep-text-inside-the-parent)

Comment: `nl2br()` - read the manual: http://php.net/nl2br

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have only 1 word.

Add `word-wrap: break-word;`

Like

```
.catDescription p {
    width: 300px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 1):

If you set a width for the paragraph then the text should wrap by default, unless specified otherwise, when the width of the paragraph is exceeded.

```
p {
    width: 300px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a non spaced string, inorder to break that, you will have to assign some fixed `width` to your paragraph and than use [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) property with a value of `break-word`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P8Gfn/)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this.

You could use some `<br>` tags, but looking at your code, I don't think it could be useful.

That's why I'm suggesting you to format your text better. You could style your `<div>` and your `<p>` to get a good-looking text. First of all, set a `max-width` to your div: this way, if a user shrinks the window, or has a very low resolution, your layout is preserved.

```
.catDescription {
    max-width: 1024px; /*Width example, you can ofc change it*/
}
```

If you have walls of text, `line-height` property can help you not getting your text too tightened. For example:

```
.catDescription p {
    line-height:130%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use line breaks: `<br>`. Insert wherever you want a newline to occur.